# Can I convert four-wire 250 volt, 30 amp dryer to two 125 volt dual outlet receptacles?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Can I use the 10 gauge wires (red, black, white, ground)from 30 amp, 250 volt dryer receptacle for two 125 volt circuits for two separate duplex receptacles? Can I use stranded wire for jumpers, or must I use solid wire?

Comment: Does the dryer need to continue in use?

Comment: Dryer moved to other location

Comment: Sharing a neutral for 2 circuits is not a good idea. Overheating on that neutral galore if / when both those circuit reaches their max rated current. *Not "cool"....* Pun also intended. **

Comment: Neutral wire now being used for 20 amp, 125 volt multi wire branch circuit, maximum 2,500 watts to each of two duplex receptacles, connected to double (dual-pole) 20 amp breaker.                                                                                                           
      Previously, same neutral wire used for 30 amp, 250 volt, 7,200 watt four wire clothes dryer receptacle. Other than being divided between two receptacles instead of just one, wired exactly the same way. If overheating is still possibility, I must be doing something wrong. I would appreciate any input!

Comment: How can I add third ceiling florescent light and switch in garage to current system in which two switches control two lights?

Answer (score 3):

You could make a MWBC out of this /3 + gnd cable and install two 20 A receptacles. You would change the 2-pole 30 A breaker to a 2-pole 20 A breaker.

If the conductors are aluminum, you would pigtail with 12 AWG copper. If the conductors are 10 AWG copper, you might be able to connect these directly to the contacts on the receptacles.

I would make these to 20 A so that if you ever needed to run heavy current demand appliances, you'd have the capability.

To install a single duplex receptacle in the box, you would split the hot sides by breaking the connecting tab. The black wire would go to the hot side of one receptacle and the red to the hot side of the other.

The neutral side tab would be left intact.

Comment: My four-wire dryer outlet is connected to a 2-pole 40 A breaker. If I replace dryer outlet with two 20 A receptacles, (total of four outlets) can I connect them to two separate 20 A breakers?

Comment: Whoops! Am being told local code might require double (dual-pole) 20 A breaker, since receptacles share the same neutral wire.

Comment: Not just local code. National code. Also a physical requirement. Not "might" require. The two hots of a MWBC *must* be on different legs of the bus so the net current in the shared neutral is the *difference* in the currents in the two hots. What is the manufacturer of your panel?

Comment: Using two duplex receptacles (giving four receptacles total) is not something I had considered. Can two duplex receptacles be installed in the current box? Would they fit and are there mounting holes?

Comment: Existing box for four-wire 30 amp dryer outlet has mounting holes perfect for two dual outlet receptacles. Wires all 10 gauge, red, black, white, ground. As I understand it, each receptacle gets a hot wire, (black or red) both share white neutral via jumpers, likewise both share ground. Will use 20 amp dual pole breaker. (All breakers in panel box are GE). Question: Can I use stranded wire for jumpers, or must I use solid wire?

Comment: Experts here have said that stranded wire can be used for jumpers (maybe even preferable). Solid #12 copper is stiff but in the past I used it to pigtail #12 and #10 aluminum. I felt it made better contact with aluminum in wire nuts. I even prefer solid copper in AlumiConn connectors. I am uncomfortable with stranded wire because I have no experience with making stranded to solid connections. Do you have copper #10 in this cable or is it aluminum?

Comment: I am using #10 stranded copper wire for jumpers. Somewhat bulkier than #10 solid wire, so  I am using small washers to cover loops around screw heads on receptacles. Some Electricians believe that stranded wire has better conductivity than solid wire if care is taken not to break off any individual strands.

Comment: You may think that adding small washers will improve the clamping of the stranded wire (and it may in fact do so), but you are introducing something which is not part of the listed device. What material would these washers be? It would be good for some of the experts to comment on the wisdom of this. It might be better to just use the screw as is.  You could perhaps use the type of receptacle which has a plate clamp accessed from the back which is tightened by the side screw. I know this is well thought of for solid conductor, but I don't know if it works for stranded.

Comment: I ended up using thin copper washers under the screw heads for my braided pigtails. Tight secure fit with no strands sticking out from under screw heads as before. Am running free-standing room air conditioner off one of the new outlets. So far, so good, AC plug and face plate for outlets remaining cool to touch, no flipped breakers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a split outlet? Why not just cap the red wire and use the black, white and ground. You have a 30 amp breaker that should be changed out to a 15 or 20 depending on the rating of the receptacle you're installing. Disconnect and cap the red wire in the panel, leave the breaker there so there are no open spaces in the panel. Install the new breaker in an available slot.

Comment: The OP might not have enough room in the original box for all the connections needed for a split duplex receptacle. In that case one might just cap the red as suggested. A person might never need two separate 20 A circuits at this one location.

Comment: Actually I think I do have room for two receptacles. Each receptacle would have 20 A available, right? This would also give me a total of four outlets instead of just two. I like it!

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do can already be accomplished by existing adaptors.
Here's an example [converting dryer plug to split receptacle](https://www.amazon.ca/Conntek-P1430611-14-30P-4-Prong-Connectors/dp/B00SOYBRCE/ref=asc_df_B00SOYBRCE/):

[image: Adaptor]

Comment: This is **DANGEROUS**. The result would be 15/20A devices running on a 30A circuit. I'd be shocked (pun intended) if UL would approve such a thing. It would be perfectly fine if it included a 20A breaker inside it, but I see no indication of that.

Comment: In addition, if you're doing the work yourself, the materials bill would be much less than what they are charging for this adapter.

Comment: @PhilippNagel Actually, as a *temporary* fix (e.g., if there were no other circuits available and this was for temporary use to be switched back to the dryer later) this makes a lot of sense. The "only" problem is that it is dangerous. Same device with a 20A breaker would be safe & useful.

Comment: @manassehkatz, how is it significantly more dangerous than running a 1A device on a 15/20A circuit?  That's something we all do all the time.  (That's not a rhetorical or sarcastic question, I'm actually curious as to what the real danger is.)

Comment: What if you have a heater or motor that partly fails so that it starts pulling 25A instead of 15A. With a 20A breaker it will trip the breaker before the power cord overheats. With a 30A breaker it will never trip and cord or motor is more likely to actually overheat and start a fire.

Comment: @manassehkatz, yes, but how is it different from an 18/2 table lamp cord plugged into a 15/20A circuit?  It's intended to carry 1A, so a partial failure could allow it to carry much more than that and start a fire.  Or to match your example, consider a [4W 120V record-player motor](https://www.amazon.ca/Panasonic-F63265G60AP-Drive-Turntable-Motor/dp/B001EY958O/). The numbers are different, but it's the same situation.  I don't see anyone worrying about it or saying it is dangerous.

Comment: I don't how all of it works - perhaps one of the more experienced pros can explain more. But my basic understanding is that devices can have smaller wires as various parts for various reasons that are built in to the listing/certification processes. For example, a lamp cord might be 18 AWG. That is far too small to carry a full 15A in an enclosed space like inside a wall. But with air circulating around it (as is the case normally with a lamp cord) and with the normal load quite limited (e.g., a lamp might be rated for a max. of 250W and typically with LEDs far less actually used), the 18 AWG

Comment: is plenty safe. If there is a short circuit then there is no issue - the 18 AWG won't be enough for more than a few seconds but the breaker will trip. If someone loads it up "a little too much", there is enough leeway in the design, even with 18 AWG, to not start a fire. There could be a problem if you loaded it up with 15A for an extended period of time, but a simple lamp would rarely fail that way - presumably enough to not be considered a problem by UL. On the other hand a **receptacle** which is at the end of an extension cord could be used for **anything**. You might intend to use this

Comment: extension for 200W of electronics. But you leave it sitting there and then a contractor comes in with a 20A big power saw. Again no problem. But then the motor starts to bind on something and **draw extra power and overheat**. If he catches it quickly (which he should for other reasons), no problem. But if he doesn't and now it is drawing 28A for an extended period of time you could have serious problems, particularly if it isn't connected directly to this "adapter" but instead of a 50' extension cord, etc. The combinations are endless and the "rules" don't protect **every** crazy action but

Comment: they help to protect against a **LOT** of crazy actions. To take it to an extreme - why bother to have branch circuit breakers at all. Let's just plug everything in directly to circuits straight (no breaker) on the panel bus. The cell phone charger only needs a fraction of an Amp. If it short circuits then the 100A main breaker will trip. Why do we need a 15A or 20A or 30A or anything else in between??? A little extreme, but hopefully you get the point. Actually, that is to partly to protect the wiring. Back to the original situation: What if you put a 50' 14 AWG extension cord on one of

Comment: those 20A receptacles with 3 15A receptacles at the end of it. Now plug in 2 x 15A heaters that draw a sustained 12A each.  With a normal 20A circuit, the breaker will trip in plenty of time to protect that 20A-rated extension cord from burning up. With this 30A-20A adapter circuit thing, the breaker **will not trip EVER** because 24A continuos is fine on a 30A circuit, but that extension cord will heat up in a hurry.

Comment: The dryer outlet  is a common outlet found on many generators. I'm guessing that is the main use for this adapter.

Comment: I HAVE used this kind of adapter on a large (6000+ Watts) portable generator. Generator does have circuit breakers.

Comment: Note: NOT plugging one of these into household socket!